# Projective $BP_\ast$-dimension of the $BP$-homology of classifying spaces of finite groups

Tags: homotopy-theory, homological-algebra, chromatic-homotopy

Fix a prime $p$ and let $G$ be a finite group. Do we know the projective dimension of $BP_\ast (BG)$ as a graded $BP_\ast$-module? Or at least that it is finite?

My guess is the following:

> The projective $BP_\ast$ dimension of $BP_\ast(BG)$ is the rank of the maximal elementary abelian $p$-subgroup of $G$.

Known cases:

- true for cyclic groups since the projective dimension of $BP_\ast(BC_p)$ as a graded $BP_\ast$-module is $1$.
- true for elementary abelian $p$-groups by work of Johnson and Wilson in "The Brown-Peterson homology of elementary $p$-groups." Amer. J. Math. 107 (1985), no. 2, 427--453.

**Remark:** Irakli Patchkoria pointed out to me that Tezuka and Yagita [Cohomology of finite groups and Brown-Peterson cohomology. II. Homotopy theory and related topics (Kinosaki, 1988), 57--69, Lecture Notes in Math., 1418, Springer, Berlin, 1990.] refer to this as ''Landweber's Conjecture''.

Comment: More accurately, Tezuka and Yagita point out that Peter Landweber conjectured this in a conference proceedings paper from 1970: [Proc. Aarhus Summer Institute of Algebraic Topology (1970), 256-269].

Comment: I wonder if the general case follows from the abelian case by Quillen's 'complex oriented descent' argument? I realize that doesn't help much...

Comment: I also wonder if a chromatic version of Quillen’s stratification argument might work. Perhaps we’re using different words for the same thing?

Comment: Very much related to the previous two comments - I would try seeing if you could get something out of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1507.06867.pdf (which doesn't consider BP, but does consider MU).